# How to code python script to run run existing task scheduler in Window

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

***please recommend any python package that is pretty much the closest to do this task.***

or the previous questions are similar to my question.

Please guide me to use library to run window task scheduler? I am going to use it to run the window task scheduler through the Django web application ?

Or else , is there any package to do for this scenario?

I would like you to guide sample code to do as the following requirement.

My job has been created on Window task scheduler already My job is responsible for executing a python file.
2.I would like you to run the job of window task scheduler in view.py on the Django web application

Comment: I know pywin32 ,but I don't see good document or code sample.